# Creating a dynamic range between two named cells with set number of columns

Tags: vba, excel, range

I need to create a dynamic range between two named cells (the cells and corresponding rows shouldn't be included in the selection). The number of columns is always the same (4), only the number of rows is changing. That's the first step.
Second one is putting several these ranges into a numbered list in another excel list, but that is something I can hopefully figure out myself. Thank you very much.

Comment: It isn't completely clear what you are trying to do. Give a specific example of two cells (e.g. A1 and A3) and explain what range you are trying to determine. What have you tried? What was the result? What was the intended result?

Answer (score 1):

I might try something like this:

```
Sub RangeBetween()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim betRange As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A1")   'sample data
Set rng2 = Range("A20")

Set betRange = Range(rng1.Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & rng2.Offset(-1, 3).Address)

End Sub
```

This is of course assuming that your named cells are along the same column. If your named cells always spread 4 columns by default, replace the Offset(-1, 3) with Offset(-1, 0).

Answer (score 0):

This code defines a named range with the name "NewNamedRange". The code assumes (and requires) that your bracketing cells are already named ranges, with the names "UpperLeft" and "LowerRight". The offset formulas exclude the bracketing cells from the named range. So if "UpperLeft" is cell D2, and "LowerRight" is cell G22, "NewNamedRange" will be the range "D3:G21". Because the named range definition is a formula, NewNamedRange will change dynamically as the bracketing cell definitions change. Hope this helps.

```
Sub NamedRange()

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
Name:="NewNamedRange", _
RefersTo:="=OFFSET(UpperLeft,1,0):OFFSET(LowerRight,-1,0)"
End Sub
```